# Testing assertDispatched only works when using event helper

Tags: laravel, testing, events, laravel-5

**Registering service provider**:

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(CartInterface::class, function ($app) {
        return new SessionCart($app['session'], $app['events']);
    });
}
```

**Firing events within the service above**:

```php
$this->events->fire('cart.added', $item);
```

**Testing the service**:

```php
public function it_can_add_an_item()
{
    Event::fake();
    $this->cartService->add(new Item);

    $this->assertEquals(1, $this->cartService->count());
    Event::assertDispatched('cart.added');
}
```

**Result**:
`The expected [cart.added] event was not dispatched.`

If instead of using `$this->events` to fire events I just use the event helper like `event('cart.added')` I'm back to green.

I'm not dying for using the object oriented approach, but I'm really curious about the reason it doesn't work here, because the event helper seems to be using an instance of the dispatcher right from the container just like I do when registering the service.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when your test is executed:

1. The laravel application is bootstrapped; it binds the non-fake event dispatcher to the service container
2. You bind the `CartInterface` to the service containing and pass the currently binded event dispatcher (the non-fake one) as a parameter
3. **After** the application has been bootstrapped, you swap the event dispatcher with the fake one, however, your `CartInterface` has already been resolved (since its a singleton) and does not know that the event dispatcher has been swapped

Therefore, the `CartInterface` still uses the non-fake event dispatcher and your tests fail if you try to make any event assertions. However, if you use the `Event` facade inside your `CartInterface`, the event dispatcher will be resolved when you are actually using it, and this is after the dispatcher has been swapped with the fake one. So in this case, you actually get the event fake you want and your tests pass.